# Call repository function with entity manager but getting namespace error

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am calling repository function with following detail

```
$ratingData = $em->getRepository(PatientFeedback::class)->getRatingReviewData($doctorId, $this->timezone);
```

and my repository class is like:

```
namespace App\Repository;

class PatientFeedbackRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
}
```

getting error like:

```
Attempted to call function \"getRatingReviewData\" from namespace \"Api\\Controller\".
```

is anything specific I am missing to use entity repository?

Comment: On where you saw in the docs you've to extend `ServiceEntityRepository` instead of `EntityRepository`???

Comment: Even better, avoid extending repository - it only leads to troubles. Use clean [constructor injection](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony) instead. It's simple and makes your code error prone

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error:

```
$em->getRepository(PatientFeedback::class)>getRatingReviewData(...)
```

to:

```
$em->getRepository(PatientFeedback::class)->getRatingReviewData(...)
```

Without the `-`, it's looking for a function nammed `getRatingReviewData` in the current namespace

Comment: its resolved with solution provided by ankit parmar

Answer (score -1):

Use EntityRepository instead of ServiceEntityRepository :

```
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
    class UsersRepository extends EntityRepository
```